# How do I use Jasper report with empty details?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print the title and footer band of a report even if there is no details row (empty list or null). Is this the default behavior of Jasper Report?

I'm getting an empty blank page instead of only title-footer bands and I cannot understand if there is a problem in my report or if Jasper works like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"`, the default is `NoPages`.

In Jaspersoft Studio you can set the attribute in the Report Properties view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property **whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"** in the source code.

When we use this property all sections other than detail band will appear when there is no data.
By default ,it is **whenNoDataType="NoPages"** i.e. when the list is empty , the page will be blank.